# Is there a way to strongly type sagas put actions?

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

In redux-thunk we can define what type of `actions` can be `dispatch`

```
enum MoviesTypes {
  ADD_MOVIES = 'ADD_MOVIES',
}

interface AddMoviesAction {
  type: typeof MoviesTypes.ADD_MOVIES;
  movies: MovieShowcase[];
}

type MoviesActionTypes = 
  | AddMoviesAction;

const addMovies = (movies: MovieShowcase[]): MoviesActionTypes => ({
  type: MoviesTypes.ADD_MOVIES,
  movies,
});

// ThunkAction<any, any, any, MoviesActionTypes> <---
// dispatch only actions inside MoviesActionTypes
const fetchNextPage = (
  page: number
): ThunkAction<Promise<void>, {}, {}, MoviesActionTypes> => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: 'BAD_TYPE' }); // error
  dispatch({ type: MoviesTypes.ADD_MOVIES, movies: [] }); // good
};
```

Is it possible to do the same on a saga ?

How can i strictly say that we can call `put` with actions inside `MoviesActionTypes` only?

```
function* fetchMovies({ page }: FetchMoviesAction) {
  yield put({ type: MoviesTypes.ADD_MOVIES, movies: [] }); // good
  yield put({ type: 'BAD_TYPE' }); // good
}

function* watchFetchMovies() {
  yield takeEvery(MoviesTypes.FETCH_MOVIES, fetchMovies);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`put` is generic:

```
export function put<A extends Action>(action: A): PutEffect<A>
```

So just write a version of `put` that is constrained to your app's action types:

```
import {
  put as putUntyped,
} from "redux-saga/effects";

export const put = <A extends FetchMoviesAction>(action: A): PutEffect<A> =>
  putUntyped(action);
```

Then use it wherever you would have used put:

```
import { put } from "...";

yield put({ type: MoviesTypes.ADD_MOVIES, movies: [] });
```